# How to display json encoded image - jquery signaturepad

Tags: php, json, image, signaturepad

I'm trying to display image that has been encoded. It looks like that:

```html
"data:image\/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOQAAAA3CAYAAAAc\/eYMAAAAuUlEQVR4nO3TMQEAMAyAsPo33Z6TMI5EAQ+zQMb8DgAeQ0KIISHEkBBiSAgxJIQYEkIMCSGGhBBDQoghIcSQEGJICDEkhBgSQgwJIYaEEENCiCEhxJAQYkgIMSSEGBJCDAkhhoQQQ0KIISHEkBBiSAgxJIQYEkIMCSGGhBBDQoghIcSQEGJICDEkhBgSQgwJIYaEEENCiCEhxJAQYkgIMSSEGBJCDAkhhoQQQ0KIISHEkBBiSAgxJIQclyE3fsX77n0AAAAASUVORK5CYII="}
```

I have tried:

`base64-decode()`

for this string without that part:

`data:image\/png;base64,`

but no result.

How should I convert image to display it? Thanks.

Edited: This image in fact is signature.I'm using jquery signaturepad. It looks like that in database:

```html
name":"My Name","output":"data:image\/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOQAAAA3CAYAAAAc\/eYMAAAAuUlEQVR4nO3TMQEAMAyAsPo33Z6TMI5EAQ+zQMb8DgAeQ0KIISHEkBBiSAgxJIQYEkIMCSGGhBBDQoghIcSQEGJICDEkhBgSQgwJIYaEEENCiCEhxJAQYkgIMSSEGBJCDAkhhoQQQ0KIISHEkBBiSAgxJIQYEkIMCSGGhBBDQoghIcSQEGJICDEkhBgSQgwJIYaEEENCiCEhxJAQYkgIMSSEGBJCDAkhhoQQQ0KIISHEkBBiSAgxJIQclyE3fsX77n0AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
```

How to display this signature?

Answer (score 0):

Just past the encoded image (replace /\ with /) in a img tag :

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOQAAAA3CAYAAAAc/eYMAAAAuUlEQVR4nO3TMQEAMAyAsPo33Z6TMI5EAQ+zQMb8DgAeQ0KIISHEkBBiSAgxJIQYEkIMCSGGhBBDQoghIcSQEGJICDEkhBgSQgwJIYaEEENCiCEhxJAQYkgIMSSEGBJCDAkhhoQQQ0KIISHEkBBiSAgxJIQYEkIMCSGGhBBDQoghIcSQEGJICDEkhBgSQgwJIYaEEENCiCEhxJAQYkgIMSSEGBJCDAkhhoQQQ0KIISHEkBBiSAgxJIQclyE3fsX77n0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=">
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh76fn4n/)

Comment: I edited my question. this image is signature - I'm using jquery signaturebox and it database it looks like that - name and output. How to display it? :)